# Solve for x if $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 .... = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've gone as far as rewriting it as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} = 2$$

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: There's a formula for the l.h.s.

Comment: This is a geometric series. Use the sum formula: $1+x+x^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}$ if $x<1$.

Comment: Hint: Calculate $2x - 2$, using the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating the series

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} x^{k-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} x^k$$

we can get the writing of the Geometric series, valid for $|x| < 1$:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Hence you have to solve

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 2$$

$$1 = 2 - 2x$$

$$2x = 1$$

$$\boxed{x = \frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for all the detail.

Comment: @Sithe You're welcome! ^^

Answer (score 7):

if $1+x+ x^2+\cdots = 2$, then $x+x^2+x^3 + \cdots = 2x$ and so $1+x+ x^2+\cdots = 2x+1$, from which we get $2 = 2x+1$ and solving gives $x = {1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use the fact that:$$1+x+x^2+...={1\over 1-x}$$ for any $$0<x<1$$ It follows that :$${1\over 1-x}=2$$ Which gives:$$2x+1=2$$ and :$$x={1\over 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$|x|<1 \to \\1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...=2\\ 1+x(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)=2\\1+x(2)=2\\x=\frac{1}{2}$$
or 
$$\\1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...=2\\ 1+x+x^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)=2\\1+x+x^2(2)=2\\2x^2+x-1=0\\x=\frac{1}{2} \color{red}{\checkmark}\\x=-1 ,\color{red}{|x|<1}$$
so $x=-1 $ is not acceptable